# Getting Postgres error in Java server when inserting timestamp

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, error-handling, timestamp

I am operating on a Spring boot platform and I am connected to a Postgres database. When I try to perform insertion, I get the following error:

```
Database error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "19" Position: 110
```

I am executing the code insertion as per below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/event", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadEvent(@RequestParam("title") String title,
                   @RequestParam("description") String description,
                   @RequestParam("start") Date start,
                   @RequestParam("end") Date end){
    // Schema
    /*
       StartTime timestamp NOT NULL,
       EndTime timestamp NOT NULL,
       Description varchar(1500),
       name  varchar(80) NOT NULL,
       DisplayPicLoc varchar(80),
       attendenceCount int
     */


    Timestamp startTime = null;
    Timestamp endTime = null;

    try{
        startTime = new Timestamp(start.getTime());
        endTime = new Timestamp(end.getTime());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.print("Date conversion error: " + e);
        return "failure";
    }

    System.out.println("Event received with Title: " + title +
            " Description: " + description +
            " Start: " + startTime +
            " End: " + endTime);

    Connection connection = DatabaseConnection.connection;
    if(connection==null){
        new DatabaseConnection();
    }
    try{
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement preparedStatement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO event " +
                       "(StartTime, EndTime, Description, name, DisplayPicLoc, attendenceCount) " +
                       "VALUES (" + startTime +
                                ", " + endTime +
                                ", " + description +
                                ", " + title +
                                ", null" +
                                ", 0);";

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate(query);
        return "success";
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Database error: " + e);
        return "failure";
    }
```

I am trying to insert an event into my database that has the following values:

```
Event received with Title: a Description: a Start: 2016-03-02 19:00:00.0 End: 2016-03-03 19:00:00.0
```

What is the reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Your usage of `PreparedStatement` is wrong. You are concatenating the values into the query string. You should use placeholders and `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()` and `PreparedStatement.setString()` instead. Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for details

Comment: Thank you. Your comment has actually fixed my error. :D